# How to build a Windows application with dependent dll?

Tags: c++, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

Created a web service application that uses some library in another project of the same solution. This library is dependent on certain DLLs which are not directly references that is I cannot add project references.

I need to ensure that when I build and publish the web service all the necessary DLLs will automatically added in the BIN directory.  I can't figure out how to do this.
My team mate suggested to put the files in the BIN directory of the web service application and then add that to source control, but I don't like putting the BIN directory in source control because that causes other problems.

Comment: add the other project as your reference to your web service. no need to worry on the references in another project because it will surely be included when you build it

Comment: Thanks for a quick response, @rhidzzz. I forget to tell you I'm also using third party DLLs which based on C++ code, so would this solution will solve my problem ?

Comment: is it working on your certain project where it referenced?

Comment: Yes, It is working fine in the same project. But I believe this dll have some system dependencies as it's working fine on my windows 7 system but the published code is not working on Windows 10. My friend suggest me to track this by using dependency walker tool. Do you have any other effective solution ?